# Restore SMS icon in default home lancher?

Tags: launcher, home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-touchwiz

My home screen used to look like this:

[image]

As you can see there's a GoSMS icon (3rd from left).

For some reason it went away after I reboot:

[image]

Anyone knows how can I restore it?

BTW i'm on Froyo 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ICS, click on the `applications` icon, then select `menu > edit`. You can now drag-and-drop any application icon you want to the row with the default icons.

Note that you can remove the phone and contacts icons, but not the applications icon.

I'm not sure if there is a similar feature in the TouchWiz launcher on Froyo, but alternatively you can look around and install a different launcher that does allows you to customize everything. You may want to start by [reading this article](http://www.androidmadefun.com/androidfun/2012/8/10/if-you-dont-like-it-change-it-the-home-screen.html)

Comment: Forgot to indicate I'm on Froyo

Comment: @IMB Ok, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks however I actually like the default launcher since it saves me some space.

Comment: @IMB According to [this post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-epic-4g/77313-removing-default-messaging-icon-form-home-page.html#post834353l) it should be possible on Froyo as well.

Comment: That did it. I actually knew that before (that's why I achieved the 1st screen shot) but I forgot it LOL. Thanks!